# Silverstripe 3 - Is there a way to force images uploaded from an HTMLEditorField into a particular directory

Tags: silverstripe

Can't see this in docs for HTMLEditorField, and likely a TinyMCE hook anyway. We have a number of HTMLEditorFields where we want images uploaded via the media manager tool to default to a defined directory instead of defaulting to /assets/Upload. Which is making that directory hard to find stuff.

I know this can be fixed with UploadField, but is there a similar way with HTMLEditorField? Even if just to set a default on a per HTMLEditorField basis?

Comment: Checkout https://www.silverstripe.org/community/forums/customising-the-cms/show/23497